# Most efficient way of handling optional post fields in Express.js app

Tags: javascript, express

I'm building an endpoint using express that has mandatory fields and non-mandatory fields in the post request. What is the most efficient way to handle this? Is it most efficient to use

```
if(field exists in req.body){
set variable
}else{try next one}
```

and repeat that code for each non-mandatory field or is there a more efficient approach?

Comment: You can use deconstruction for required params like: `const { required1, required2, ...} = req.body;` after that you can handle non-mandatory fields.

Comment: How would I check that each req.body field has a value and doesn't just leave it undefined?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an object with the default values, and then spread the body of your message. The resulting object will have all the values of the request body plus the ones that were optional that weren't set by the user. For example:

```
const defaultValues = {
  value1: 1,
  value2: 2,
}

const body = {
  value1: 3
}

const bodyWithDefaults = {
  ...defaultValues, ...body
}

console.log(bodyWithDefaults)
>>> { value1:3, value2:2 }
```

Comment: I see, so in your example, defaultValues contains all possible values?  I would be able to set optional fields to empty strings for example by default, and in the body object I would set each required value to the req.body value, which would use the default value if not sent.